# adjusting the length of border-bottom on a <li> element

Tags: html, css, list, hover, html-lists

I was toying around with this navbar and I've managed to get everything almost just right, except for this one small problem. To put it simply whenever I hover over one of the words in the navbar a small red line appears under it. The only problem I have with it is that I would like to extend that red line just a little.

The only other time I've managed to get an extended red line on this thing is when I use this code:

```
li.nav2:hover {
  border-bottom:3px solid red;
  padding-bottom:1px;
}
```

Now the problem with that is that it kinda ruins the flow of the navbar.

Here is my jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/q23XN/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

The best way to do this according to your functionality is to use a child element that is positioned absolutely to the `<a>` that will serve as the border:

#### HTML:

```
<li class="nav1"><a href="http://www.google.com/">home<b/></a></li>
```

**Notice the new `<b/>` in there.**

#### CSS:

```
li.nav1 a, li.nav2 a
{
    position: relative;
}

li.nav1 a b, li.nav2 a b
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: -20px;

    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    background: red;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

li.nav1 a:hover b, li.nav2 a:hover b{
    display: block;
}
```

By positioning the `<a>` elements relatively, I can position a child element, which I called `<b>` below it (using `top: 100%`). Then by using padding on that element, I can make it wider than the parent and slide it to the left using `left: -20px`. (You can change the additional width, but be sure that the same number is set in `padding:` and `left:`).

Finally, I set its display to be `none` normally, and then when the parent `<a>` receives a hover event, I set its display to `block` using this selector:

```
li.nav1 a:hover b, li.nav2 a:hover b
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q23XN/8/)

---

### Other ideas:

You could do this with side padding on your `<a>`:

```
li a
{
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q23XN/2/)

---

If you want to only extend the `<a>` width onHover, you could do this with `li a:hover`:

```
li a:hover
{
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

But this will make the links get wider and may affect the position of the links.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q23XN/6/)

---

If you want to maintain the `<a>` width, you could do this with the entire `<li>` and set the margin bottom to be the negative of the border width:

```
li.nav1:hover, li.nav2:hover {
    border-bottom:3px solid red;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q23XN/4/)

---

### Note:

For one thing, in your original fiddle, your top bar's selector was

```
li.nav1 a:hover {
```

While your bottom bar's selector was

```
li.nav2:hover {
```

So you were adding the padding to the `<li>`s, rather than the `<a>`s in the second nav.

Comment: pretty close but i think the issue with this, is that it also kinda extends the link area

Comment: hmm still runs into the problem of extending the link area

Comment: If you look, the link area is confined to the text. The border does show up while hovering on the li, because that's what I'm telling it to do, but the link itself is only the text.

Comment: ohhhh didnt notice that the first time,but even though the link area is confined to the text the :hover is still activating outside the area of the text.

Comment: @user3470947 I added one more revision. This is if you only want the border to be activated while the link is being hovered over, but it may cause the text to move when hovered.

Comment: got the jsfiddle link?

Comment: sorry didnt know you put the revision in your original post. aside from the text moving this one is pretty good but the :hover still seems to function when i drag my cursor slowly to the left.

Comment: @user3470947 Right, because the text grows onHover. There's really no way to get around this unless you have a child element that functions as the border.

Comment: @user3470947 Check my final edit (at the top of my post): http://jsfiddle.net/q23XN/8/

Comment: so your essentially saying that a child element would have to function as the bottom-border then

Comment: @user3470947 yes... the border is the border; the border can't extend outside of the element. Since that seems to be what you want you have to have an additional element that is wider than the real element.

Comment: i think this may actually be it! definitely alot to take in, altleast for me. oh and could you explain what exactly the <b /> is, iam pretty sure its not a bold element or is it.

Comment: @user3470947 In this case, `<b/>` is a custom element I defined to be the border (note that this is an HTML5 feature and will require a docType in IE). `<b/>` is the equivalent of `<b></b>` which is also used to denote bold text, but in this case alone, since I have CSS saying that it is a block element, it functions as such.

Comment: oh i see its html5, definitely explains why i didnt know what it was. could i theoretically do the same with <i />.

Comment: @user3470947 Yes. You can do it with anything. You could use `<shellfish>` and it would still work as long as you have the doctype and CSS for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the nav2 to keep it's height but have the same look as the first nav, then all you need to add is the "a" to the:

```
li.nav2:hover {
border-bottom:3px solid red;
padding-bottom:1px;
}
```

So it would then be:

```
li.nav2 a:hover {
border-bottom:3px solid red;
padding-bottom:1px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this, add padding

```
li.nav2 a:hover {
border-bottom:3px solid red;
padding: 0 10px 1px 10px;

}
```

Comment: very interesting definitely the closest i've seen to getting it the way i want. but i did happen to notice a small flaw, when i place the cursor over the text and slowly drag it to the left the :hover still seems the function after my cursor is off the text

Comment: ok, i have now surrounded each <li> with the a tag. check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q23XN/7/